# Google Finance API - how to get day's range?

Tags: api, finance

I am aware Google finance API is deprecated, however the stock quotes web queries like this one still works flawlessly:
http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=aapl

It is also more reliable and faster than yahoo finance. However I cannot get day's range (low - high) from the above API, which is why I still rely on using yahoo finance API - which is slow and unreliable.

I have an application that uses both google finance and yahoo finance APIs to get stock quotes and related info. The reason I still use Google finance API is that it actually gives me more recent - near real time stock quotes, as opposed to yahoo's 15 minute delayed quotes. Also, it seems always faster than Yahoo. Yahoo finance stopped working twice last week, resulted furies from my users.

The problem is I cannot find documentation for Google finance API, and cannot find days' range (low - high) from the stock quotes. If anyone knows how to do this, or knows where to get the old deprecated documentation, please let me know. I will even reward person with correct answers.

Comment: Anyone?? how to get day's range from google finance?

Answer (score 1):

First, thanks for asking cuz your question is the answer to what I wanted :-)

See if this works for you: http://www.networkerror.org/component/content/44.html?task=view

It is also undocumented, of course, and you will have to fiddle with the resulting file....

-Alex